# How to get contacts from an Android phone to an iPhone?

Tags: sync, ios, data-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I transfer my contacts from an iPhone to an HTC Inspire?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/how-can-i-transfer-my-contacts-from-an-iphone-to-an-htc-inspire)

I use Google to maintain my contacts, which syncs to my Android device. However, I'm switching to an iPhone 4. Will it be easy to transfer contact information?

Answer (score 3):

The Mail, Contacts, and Calendars settings allow you to sync all 3 from multiple different web services to the built in Mail, Contacts, and Calendars apps. These should automatically sync when you open the different apps.

The contacts will be merged by default, but you can filter based on source i.e. Gmail, My PC, etc.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy if you set up [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/) on the iPhone.  Sync can also work with multiple devices with the same account at the same time - I have an iPhone and an iPad set up this way.  If I add a contact or appointment to one of them, it shows up on the other as well as in GMail.  I'm fairly you could actually keep an Android phone and an iPhone synchronized this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the iPhone automatically syncs, but you can download an app that will sync your Google contacts with your iPhone from the app store.

Comment: Happen to know which apps?