# How can I transfer my contacts from an iPhone to an Android device?

Tags: contacts, ios, data-transfer

I tried to transfer data from my 3 year old iPhone to my new HTC Inspire via bluetooth but it keeps saying the two are "paired but not connected". Seems I can't get past this problem.

How can I transfer info from my old phone to the new?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Google's Contact Sync to transfer them.

It's kind of complex to describe, but you can find Google
s official guide [here](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740)

Comment: +1 use the cloud, any contacts that you sync up to GMail from an iOS device will appear in Android's Contacts (as long as you have the same Google Account setup on your phone).